# Conditional JSON serialization using C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a class that I serialize to JSON in C# and post to a RESTful web service.  I have a requirment that if one field is filled out another field not be present.  The service errors if both fields are serialized into the JSON object.  My class looks like this:

```
    [DataContract(Name = "test-object")]
public class TestObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // If string-value is not null or whitespace do not serialize bool-value
    [DataMember(Name = "bool-value")]
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }

    // If string-value is null or whitespace do not serialize it
    [DataMember(Name = "string-value")]
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

As noted in the comments, if StringValue has a value don't put BoolValue in the JSON object.  If StringValue is blank, don't put in StringValue but instead put in BoolValue.

I found how to do this with XML serialization, but cannot find a way this works with JSON serialization.  Is there conditional JSON serialization on C#?

Comment: this question is not quite "similar", but the answer might apply to your case. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29173426/526704

Comment: What are you using to serialize Newtonsoft or what's included in .NET ? Maybe there are events you can hook into each time a property is serialized and skip by observing what's been serialized at that point.

Comment: I'm using what is built into .Net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are using the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  In that case, you can:

1. Disable direct serialization of your properties with the attribute [`[IgnoreDataMember]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. Create proxy `string` and `bool?` properties for serialization that return null when they should not be serialized.  These can be `private`.
3. Set [`[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on these proxy properties to suppress output of nulls.

Thus:

```
[DataContract(Name = "test-object")]
public class TestObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string StringValue { get; set; }

    bool ShouldSerializeStringValue()
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StringValue);
    }

    // If string-value is not null or whitespace do not serialize bool-value
    [DataMember(Name = "bool-value", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    bool? SerializedBoolValue {
        get
        {
            if (!ShouldSerializeStringValue())
                return BoolValue;
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            BoolValue = (value ?? false); // Or don't set it at all if value is null - your choice.
        }
    }

    // If string-value is null or whitespace do not serialize it
    [DataMember(Name = "string-value", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    string SerializedStringValue {
        get
        {
            if (ShouldSerializeStringValue())
                return StringValue;
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            StringValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Incidentally, this will also work with [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), which respects [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).