# Promoting single child json nodes in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am serializing C# Objects in a Windows Universal App to JSON, using a [custom Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173196/c-sharp-json-serialization-use-value-instead-of-property-name) to name the nodes after the `description` string in my object. So instead of

```
{  
   "description":"upper-left",
   "value":23
},
{  
   "description":"upper-right",
   "value":24
}
```

I get

```
[
   {  
      "upper-left":23
   },
   {  
      "upper-right":24
   }
]
```

This works fine for me, using an adapted version of the Converter. However, I would like to collect these key:value pairs in a single node, like this:

```
{  
   "upper-left":23,
   "upper-right":24
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom converter for this -

```
internal class MyObjectJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dataList = value as List<RootObject>;

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var data in dataList)
        {   
            writer.WritePropertyName(data.description);
            writer.WriteValue(data.value);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

where -

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}


var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<RootObject> {
            new RootObject
            {
                description = "upper-left",
                value = 23
            },
            new RootObject
            {
                description = "upper-right",
                value = 24
            }
        }, jss);
```