# write json "value" : "value"

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I'm using newtonsoft in my .net core project and came across a particular json format.
I've got a list and the 'normal' json that come out after serialization is something like this:

```
  {
      "id": "0124",
      "entities": [
        {
          "name": "chris",
          "surname": "green"
        },
        {
          "name": "albert",
          "surname": "red"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I need to transform it in something like:

```
  {
      "id": "0124",
      "entities": [
        {
          "chris": "green",
          "albert": "red"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I don't know how many entities there could be inside my list.

Thank you all

EDIT

Thanks for the help guys, so this is the code:

```
var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                new BulkRegisterDto
                {
                    Id = "0124",
                    Entities = entities
                }
            );


public class BulkRegisterDto
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id{ get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "entities")]
        public IList<Person> Entities { get; set; }
    }

 public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

These are not the real properties. I'm trying to use a dynamic JObject. We will see if it works

Comment: Please post the code you are using to to serialize the data and some sample data so we can reproduce the output

Comment: @John wouldn't it be better to use a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` as neither name nor surname are guaranteed to be uniquely identifiable? Of course I'd replace the Tuple with some custom class that does the same but has more descript names instead of Item1 and Item2

Comment: What you have in the `entities` property is basically `Dictionary<string, string>`. ie. `public class Container { public Dictionary<string, string> Entities { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>(); }`

Comment: `List<Tuple<string, string>>` will be serialized as `[ { "Item1": "a", "Item2": "b" }, { ... } ]`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I believe a Dictionary should not be used here. Let's say you use the surname as the key, what if you have two people with the surname "Doe"? Or if you use the first name as the key, what if you have two people called "John"?

Comment: can i have sample data that your fetching in entities

Comment: Could you use some kind of mapping to DTO object for serializing?

Comment: Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173196/c-sharp-json-serialization-use-value-instead-of-property-name) SO question and answer I was able to produce [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rp4x29) code that does something very similar, I can't get it to output quite correctly though

Comment: @MindSwipe JSON objects are specified as "A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array." *(from [JSON.org](https://www.json.org/))* **You can't have duplicate names.** If the OP wants to serialize data that behave like that, he can't use surnames as keys, period, at least not if he wants to produce legal JSON. See [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/?json=%7B"a":%20"b","a":%20"c"%7D) for an example.

Comment: @MindSwipe Even the code in the answer here doesn't support duplicate keys, and you will get a "Can not add property chris to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object." ArgumentException.

Comment: I should have made it more clear that it was a rhetorical question... , I am quite aware you can't add duplicate keys to a Dictionary, and my argument against using `Dictionary<string, string>` and why you should use something else. I would make a custom class that has three properties, `Name`, `Surname` and `Id` and just having a List of that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize your json to DTO:

```
[DataContract]
private class Person
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
private class Entities
{
    [DataMember(Name = "entities")]
    public Person[] Persons { get; set; }
}
```

and then build expected json with raw `JObject` and `JArray`

```
var input = "{\r\n  \"entities\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"name\": \"chris\",\r\n      \"surname\": \"green\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"name\": \"albert\",\r\n      \"surname\": \"red\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}";
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entities>(input);

var root = new JObject();
var innerObject = new JObject();

root.Add("entities", new JArray {innerObject});

foreach (var entry in json.Persons)
    innerObject.Add(entry.Name, entry.Surname);
```

If you call `root.ToString()` you will get

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "chris": "green",
      "albert": "red"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Aleks Andreev I set your answer as the right one because it solves the problem but i prefer a better approach and I created my custom json converter using @MindSwipe comment.

This is my code below:

```
public class BulkEntityConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override object ReadJson(
            JsonReader reader,
            Type objectType,
            object existingValue,
            JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var obj = (JObject)JObject.ReadFrom(reader);

            JProperty property = obj.Properties().FirstOrDefault();
            // I didn't use this method
            return new BulkRegisterDto
            {
                Id = property.Name,
                Entities = new List<Person>()
            };
        }

        public override void WriteJson(
            JsonWriter writer,
            object value,
            JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            BulkRegisterDto permission = (BulkRegisterDto)value;

            var innerEntities = new JObject();
            foreach (var entry in permission.Entities)
            {
                innerEntities.Add(entry.Name, entry.Surname);
            }

            var root = new JObject
            {
                { "id", permission.Id},
                { "entities", new JArray { innerEntities } }
            };

            root.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type t)
        {
            return typeof(BulkRegisterDto).IsAssignableFrom(t);
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
```

Using this way i can get a clear class where to use my json converter like:

```
var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(manager, new BulkEntityConverter());
```

where `manager` is my BulkRegisterDto object

Thanks for all the support guys

Comment: Well done. Also you can inherit your `BulkEntityConverter` from  `JsonConverter<BulkRegisterDto>` so you don't need to implement `CanConvert` and cast `value` to actual type

Comment: Good hint. Thanks